# Associating multiple models in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, associations

I am currently working on an application in CakePHP to display (but not modify) the contents of a legacy database. I am not able to change the database structure in any way.

There are six tables I am working with and the relationships are outlined in this awful paint diagram:

[image: DB relations]

I have currently defined the models as follows:

http://pastebin.com/4aEaSnQp

(I decided to put it in a PasteBin as it is a bit of a wall of text, I am happy to edit it into the post if preferred).

What I would like to do is use one controller to pass relevant linked data from my controller to the view from essentially all of these tables. However, even if I set recursion to 2 the links only seem to go so far - for example if I try to find data from the 'Ctit' table with code like this:

```
$this->set('contracts',$this->Ctit->find('all',
            array(
            'recursion' => 2,
            'conditions' => array('Title.TITNO' => $id),
            'fields' => array('Contract.CONNO','Title.TITLE','Contract.CONDATE','Territory.DESCRIPTION')
            )
        ));
```

The resulting query does not include the "Territory" table and so throws back an error.

What am I doing wrong here? Is it possible to retrieve the data in this way or might I have to run multiple finds or write my own queries (something I am hoping to avoid)?

Thanks in advance,

Kez

Comment: Have you tried using [Containable Behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. However, I may be misunderstanding how Containable Behaviour works, doesn't it help limit the number of results returned? While I am trying to expand them.

I tried enabling it and adding "$this->Ctit->contain('Territory.DESCRIPTION');", then I got an error which said:

Model "Ctit" is not associated with model "Territory" [CORE\Cake\Model\Behavior\ContainableBehavior.php

Comment: It limits the result if you want to (which is one will usually want), but if you set nested `contain`, it can expand them forever. Essentially, it gives you the power to decide what gets retrieved from the database, and not to the `recursive` option. Your other option is to use joins (always have trouble finding the link to that docs, but look it up). Whichever you decided, please keep in mind that you want to retrieve data for 6 models at ones... That'll escalate quickly (if you want to do a find(all) instead of a find(first), for example).

Comment: (read the other part of your comment). Ctit is not associated with Territory; Citit is associated with Contract and Contract to Territory, so you'll have to do `$this->Ctit->find('first',array('contain'=>array('Contract'=>'Territory')))`

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working, however if I add a 'fields' parameter it is unable to locate any values in the Territory table. Is there any way to specify fields while using nested contain?

Comment: Yes, please read the full docs I provided, specially the part of [deeper associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations).

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah I was trying that but it wasn't working - I realised it was because I was using all capitals for the column names and Cake was interpreting it as another model.

Thanks for all your help - if you want to condense our discussion into an answer I'll be happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... condensing the comments.

Basically it's a Containable problem. To get *everything* related to a single model (meaning, the 5 other models), a way to do it would be like

```
$this->Ctit->find('all', array(
                         'contain' => array(
                            'Royalty',
                            'Title',
                            'Contract' => array('Publisher', 'Territory')
)
```

You can also add options to that array, like any other query, for example `order`, `fields`, `conditions`, etc.
Example:

```
$this->Ctit->find('all', array(
                         'contain' => array(
                            'Royalty' => array('order' => 'id DESC'),
                            'Title' => array('fields' => array('id', 'name'),
                            'Contract' => array('Publisher', 
                                                'Territory' => array('conditions' => array('name' => 'terr'))
)
```

One thing to have in mind is to always use

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

(mind that **s** in `actsAs`, some people have had trouble because of that) otherwise your models won't behave containabl-y and you'd think this whole thing doesn't work.

Containable behaviour is useful for this, because you don't have to do a lot of finds, but keep in mind that cake does a lot of queries behind scenes to use containable. If you want this to be just *one big* query, use [joins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables) (found it!)

Also, be aware that this query might get big real quick. You are basically asking for *all* records with *all* 5 associations, when you reach a memory limit notice you are going to remember me. I doubt you want to show *all* data for *every* record on one view, so reconsider, maybe a simple paginate first and then a single view for each single record (in that case, the find will be a `find('first')` and that's lot better than `find('all')`.